# Create form dynamic depending of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on ASP.Net Core MVC and I have checkboxes as:

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="10" value="10">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="10">10sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="15" value="15">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="15">15sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="30" value="30">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="30">30sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="45" value="45">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="45">45sec</label>
</div>
```

Now I want to add dynamic cards depending of checked checkboxes like:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("10");
  var text = document.getElementById("10secs");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//dropzone script
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", {
  url: "/test/create",
  // acceptedFiles: accept,
  maxFilesize: 3.0,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  createImageThumbnails: false,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  removedfile: function(file) {
    var name = file.name;
    file.previewElement.remove();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/test/delete',
      data: "fileName=" + name,
      dataType: 'html'
    });
  },
  maxFiles: 1,
  maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
    this.removeAllFiles();
    this.addFile(file);
  },
  init: function() {
    var drop = this;
    this.on('error', function(file, errorMessage) {
      if (errorMessage.indexOf('Error 404') !== -1) {
        var errorDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]');
        errorDisplay[errorDisplay.length - 1].innerHTML = 'Error 404: The upload page was not found on the server';
      }
      if (errorMessage.indexOf('File is too big') !== -1) {
        alert('i remove current file');
        // i remove current file
        drop.removeFile(file);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5.9.3/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="10" value="10" onclick="myFunction()">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="10">10sec</label>
</div>


<div class="row" id="10secs" style="display: none">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">30sec</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="clsbox-1">
            <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want to do that for all checkboxes, but as you can see, I have a dropzone function for one dropzone, how can I do it dynamically depending on the selected checkbox, I should have one dropzone for each one. I'm also aware that there is a better way to achieve the dynamic functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the checkboxes to be multiple selectable, I suggest you create a drop zone for each checkbox. When you select two check boxes at the same time, two drop zones can appear at the same time.

Of course, you may want to process the image uploaded by each checkbox differently, and you can pass a parameter(For example:"id") to the controller to perform the corresponding operation.

Below is my test code, you can refer to it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5.9.3/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="10" value="10">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="10">10sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="15" value="15">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="15">15sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="30" value="30">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="30">30sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="45" value="45">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="45">45sec</label>
</div>


<div class="row" id="10secs" style="display: none">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">10sec</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="clsbox-1">
            <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone10">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="15secs" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">15sec</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div>
                    <div class="clsbox-1">
                        <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone15">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="30secs" style="display: none">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">30sec</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div>
                    <div class="clsbox-1">
                        <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone30">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="45secs" style="display: none">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">45sec</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <div class="clsbox-1">
            <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone45">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var id;
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function () {
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        var text = document.getElementById(id+"secs");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            
            text.style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            text.style.display = "none";
        }


        var Dropzoneid = "#mydropzone" + id;
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone(Dropzoneid, {
            url: "/home/create",
            // acceptedFiles: accept,
            maxFilesize: 3.0,
            uploadMultiple: false,
            createImageThumbnails: false,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function (file) {
                var name = file.name;
                file.previewElement.remove();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/test/delete',
                    data: "fileName=" + name,
                    dataType: 'html'
                });
            },
            maxFiles: 1,
            maxfilesexceeded: function (file) {
                this.removeAllFiles();
                this.addFile(file);
            },
            init: function () {
                var drop = this;
                this.on('error', function (file, errorMessage) {
                    if (errorMessage.indexOf('Error 404') !== -1) {
                        var errorDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]');
                        errorDisplay[errorDisplay.length - 1].innerHTML = 'Error 404: The upload page was not found on the server';
                    }
                    if (errorMessage.indexOf('File is too big') !== -1) {
                        alert('i remove current file');
                        // i remove current file
                        drop.removeFile(file);
                    }
                });
                this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {
                        data.append("id", id);
                    });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Yes, what you mentioned in your comment is achievable. If you want to upload with one click of a button, you don't need to use dropzone, you can upload via the form.

First, you need to have a model to receive the files corresponding to the four checkboxes. For example:

```
public class FileList
{
     public List<IFormFile> Files10 { get; set; }
     public List<IFormFile> Files15 { get; set; }
     public List<IFormFile> Files30 { get; set; }
     public List<IFormFile> Files45 { get; set; }
}
```

In your view:

```
@model Project.Models.FileList

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="10" value="10">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="10">10sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="15" value="15">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="15">15sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="30" value="30">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="30">30sec</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="45" value="45">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="45">45sec</label>
</div>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="CreateFile" method="post">
    <div class="row" id="10secs" style="display: none">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <h4 class="card-title">10sec</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div>
              <div class="clsbox-1">
                  <input type="file" multiple asp-for="@Model.Files10" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="15secs" style="display: none">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <h4 class="card-title">15sec</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div>
              <div class="clsbox-1">
                  <input type="file" multiple asp-for="@Model.Files15" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="30secs" style="display: none">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <h4 class="card-title">30sec</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div>
              <div class="clsbox-1">
                  <input type="file" multiple asp-for="@Model.Files30" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="45secs" style="display: none">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header">
             <h4 class="card-title">45sec</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div>
              <div class="clsbox-1">
                  <input type="file" multiple asp-for="@Model.Files45" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="submit" style="display: none">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    var id;
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function () {
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        var text = document.getElementById(id+"secs");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            text.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            text.style.display = "none";
            var IsChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]");
            var show = "none";
            for (var i = 0; i < IsChecked.length; i++) {
                if (IsChecked[i].checked) {
                    show = "block";
                }
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById("submit").style.display = show;
        }
    })
</script>
```

Your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateFile(FileList fileList)
{
    return View();
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it works!, one more question, what if I want to upload all images on one submit button click instead upload them automatically after being added to dropzone, that is possible?

Comment: Hi @Jesus, I updated my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: Sir, it is possible to keep the dropzone on your last edit?